# HTTP.post to FCM Server not working

Tags: http, push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Ionic 2 with [HTTP native module](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) to make a post request to FCM server for push notifications. The code I am using is:

```
        HTTP.post(
          "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
          {
            "notification": {
              "title": "Notification title",
              "body": "Notification body",
              "sound": "default",
              "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
              "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
            },
            "data": {
              "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
            },
            "to": "device token",
          },
          {
            Authorization: {
              key: "AUTHORIZATION KEY HERE"
           }
          })
```

Its giving me an error:

```
Unimplemented console API: Unhandled Promise rejection:
Unimplemented console API: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
```

I tried the post request with Postman, it works perfectly fine delivering push notifications.

The code with Postman is:

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=Authorisation Key
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 446e253b-179a-d19b-21ea-82d9bb5d4e1c

{
  "to": "Device Token",
  "data": {
    "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
   }
     "notification":{
    "title":"Notification title",
    "body":"Notification body",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
  },
}
```

Questions:

1. I am unable to add `content-type` to the header in the HTTP post request, but it works with postman.
2. If I try to add a `function(response) {` to get the response from the server, it gives me an error. The documentation for the same is at https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using `HTTP native module`? Angular has a built in `Http`.

Using this one (importing `HttpModule` from `@angular/http` in your `NgModule`) you can just call

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

......

constructor(public http: Http) { }

sendPushNotification(deviceId: string) {
  let url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  let body = 
   {
     "notification": {
         "title": "Notification title",
         "body": "Notification body",
         "sound": "default",
         "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
         "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
     },
     "data": {
         "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
     },
     "to": "device token"
   };
let headers: Headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key='+this.someKey
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

console.log(JSON.stringify(headers));

  this.http.post(url, body, headers).map(response => {
    return response;
  }).subscribe(data => {
     //post doesn't fire if it doesn't get subscribed to
     console.log(data);
  });
}
```

---

```
push.on('notification', (data) => {
 if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
          // if application open, show popup
          let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: data.title,
            message: data.message,
            buttons: [{
              text: 'Ignore',
              role: 'cancel'
            }, {
              text: 'Go to',
              handler: () => {
                //TODO: Your logic here
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventsPage, {message: data.message});
              }
            }]
          });
          confirmAlert.present();
        } else {
          //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
          //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventsPage, {message: data.message});
        }
      });
      push.on('error', (e) => {
        alert(e);
      });

    });
```

Comment: its giving me EXCEPTION: Response with status: 401 OK which according to documentation is for invalid key ... but have checked twice 

headers.append('Authorization', 'key=my authorization key here');

Comment: Can you check if the `request headers` in your request (you can check with chrom console) contain the  right value?

Comment: its showing "to" key in red ,, .....

{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Notification title",
    "body": "Notification body",
    "sound": "default",
    "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
  },
  "data": {
    "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!"
  },
  "to": "this part is in parsed view is showing red"
}

Comment: i tried with topics too "to": "/topics/cooking" its still showing 401 error

Comment: **is 'key='+someKey and 'key=someKey' same ? ** because console is telling me " The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentification" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.

Error 401"
 and i tried with legacy server key also still not working :(

Comment: As long as someKey is the value of your key, then yes

Comment: hi ivaro18 , i am pretty sure it cant be done directly via http post firebase must be having some authorization issues or something, have tested every solution mentioned and looked all over with no one using direct http post, so would need to go via server route, can you be kind enough to share a server code example and installation documentation on a web server

Comment: @dhruv weird that it **does** work with postman but for some reason cannot work with `http`. Can't test it myself at the moment though. Don't have a lot of time to spare but I created my server with `Java + Spring` (link in the end). The code for sending the pushnotification is the same as the guide you used (basically Kotlin code from previous question)  https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: it's got something to do with chrome provisional headers, will come back to this http post once i figure out how to send them via server.

Comment: is it necessary to pass deviceId into the function ?

Comment: i think i missed the important step of all post does not fire if it does not subscribe to .... how can i prevent that from happening, i am doing it in reverse , once the post executes then sendnotification

Comment: Then subscribe to the post and send the notification within the post? I don't understand your problem to be honest

Comment: finally was able to make it work , have made the changes to the code , thanks for the help

Comment: cool! nice, but the only thing you had to do was convert to `RequestOptions`? damn hahah

Comment: yes, was mentioned on angular documentation, they have great hero app documentation

Comment: would you have any idea as to how to use "click_action" to go to particular page on my app ?

Comment: you can call functions on click like `<div (click)="someFunction()">` but I doubt that this is what you meant?

Comment: i meant for push notifications , when i send a notification for some activity lets say a new chat message i want to go to that page on notification click

Comment: Edited the question with how I currently do it. I do not have that it goes to a specific page depending on the pushnotification. However this is definitely possible, I believe firebase supports a kind of 'additional data' when sending a notification, then you can just retrieve that data in the `handler` and do your calculations/processing/navigating there.