# Angular2 HTTP Post Request to FCM Server not working

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, http-post, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Ionic 2 and angular http i am attempting to make http post request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, the request tested with postman works perfectly fine

this question is a follow-up question to my this question :

[HTTP.post to FCM Server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033895/http-post-to-fcm-server-not-working/41034358?noredirect=1#comment69284342_41034358)

**console tells error to be** The request was missing an Authentification Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentification" of the FCM documentation, at firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server. Error 401

the code for http request is

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

......

constructor(public http: Http) { }

sendPushNotification(deviceId: string) {
  let url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  let body = 
   {
     "notification": {
         "title": "Notification title",
         "body": "Notification body",
         "sound": "default",
         "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
         "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
     },
     "data": {
         "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
     },
     "to": "device token"
   };

  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'key='+someKey);

  this.http.post(url, body, headers).map(response => {
    return response;
  }).subscribe(data => {
     //post doesn't fire if it doesn't get subscribed to
     console.log(data);
  });
}
```

headers from chrome console are as follows :

General Headers

Request URL:https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 
Remote Address:[2404:6800:4009:807::200a]:443

Response headers

access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:8100
access-control-expose-headers:Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server
alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
cache-control:private, max-age=0
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:260
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Thu, 08 Dec 2016 12:36:14 GMT
expires:Thu, 08 Dec 2016 12:36:14 GMT
server:GSE
status:401
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block

Request Headers

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
content-type:application/json
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
{notification: {title: "Notification title", body: "Notification body", sound: "default",…},…}
data
:
{hello: "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device new Message!"}
notification
:
{title: "Notification title", body: "Notification body", sound: "default",…}
to
:
"/topics/cooking"

Comment: Can you give us the Header that is actually sent from you borwser? It should be in DevTools (F12 for chrome) network tab. Obfuscate the key of course before posting it in your question.

Comment: request headers are : 
Provisional headers are shown
content-type:application/json
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: So the Authorization.append(key, value) failed for some reason and since the key was not sent, you get the error. Is the someKey value defined? Try adding you FCM key manually in the Code and see waht happens and then append from the variable.

Comment: headers.append('Authorization', 'key=AAAA****bHw3*****'); i am using it like this ...

Comment: results are same even when calling from variable

Comment: Look at this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger Seems like your request is being blocked in chrome but in this question you can find out why.

Comment: is it possible to base64 encode header as one of the reasons is header being too long ?

Comment: No it is not. I'm not aware of it being done. The web server should be aware of the encoding and it is forbidden to send encoded data in the http protocol.

Comment: i was able to make provisional headers go away by adding retry and some delay  with this code , .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500)).timeout(2000, new Error('delay exceeded')) but request headers still don't contain my authorization header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got this working by adding headers as requestoptions ,

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key='+this.someKey
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```