# What Are the difference between GCM and FCM?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to know about the difference between GCM and FCM.

why GCM re placed by FCM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311188/migration-from-gcm-to-fcm-needed

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311188/migration-from-gcm-to-fcm-needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand.

Benefits.
The new FCM SDK:

1.Simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.

2.Enables a new serverless notifications solution with a web console, Firebase Notifications. With Firebase Notifications, anyone can send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights. They can then evaluate notification effectiveness by assessing the built-in Notifications Funnel Analysis in the console.

Refer this link for More info -- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Comment: cons: gives no control for non-data notification when the app is in background

Answer (score 0):

From Docs

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core 
>   infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

For more details read [GCM and FCM Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) or if you want to migrate from GCM to FCM have a look into [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://Migrate%20a%20GCM%20Client%20App%20for%20Android%20to%20Firebase%20Cloud%20Messaging)