# FCM client library pros over GCM (For a push delivery service)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing a push notification delivery service (Something like 1Signal) in Iran. We're using Firebase as push provider as Google says so, but for client library can't decide over using FCM or GCM. 
We wan't to report the delivery of a notification or clicking on it and also flexibility on handling notification for developers.

**I've read the official docs and SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311188/migration-from-gcm-to-fcm-needed/37314483#37314483)** which are not very helpful and the fact that I've not found a push delivery service using FCM in their SDKs adds more confusion.

So, an specific and technical comparison would be great or tell me **why should I use FCM SDK in my SDK for a push delivery system**?

Comment: I believe that FCM is direct successor of GCM and Google will only continue to support FCM in the future

Comment: I know that, I just want to know what kind of features can I expect in fcm sdk for future? Currently it's just has more method count and is bigger in size :)

Comment: hmm. i will just delete that comment then.

Comment: You're not required to use FCM... GCM is a essentially a protocol for push messages, not only a product platform like Firebase. It only makes sense to use FCM if you are already using the other Firebase services.