# Appsflyer uninstall tracking with GCM

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

We are using appsflyer sdk for uninstall tracking. We are just using GCM and not integrated firebase-messaging. Is it ok to keep using only gcm with appsflyer even after appsflyer sdk 4.7 +

Comment: From week 33, business has reported issue that uninstall events are underrated (received less events on appsflyer than expected). I was in doubt that may be we need to integrate firebase-messaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to keep using only GCM with appsflyer even after sdk 4.7 +

**Yes**, AppsFlyer SDK v4.7.+ supports both GCM and Firebase

> From week 33, business has reported issue that uninstall events are underrated (received less events on appsflyer than expected).

First of all you can contact `support@appsflyer.com` about discrepancy.

> I was in doubt that may be we need to integrate firebase-messaging

You can read answered question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311188/migration-from-gcm-to-fcm-needed)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I can continue using GCM. In our code we have a service extended from InstanceIDListenerService to handle token refresh. But it was not registered in manifest. I think that could have been issue.